# Flask running in WSL2 cannot connect to postgres running on windows (did work with WSL1)

Tags: postgresql, flask, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have started to develop a Flask app using VSCode/WSL1 and have then migrated from WSL1 to WSL2.

Since then, I cannot connect to my the database running on windows using "localhost"

DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://sysadmin:mypassword@localhost/db_dev'

I can only connect if use the ip address found in "cat /etc/resolv.conf"

DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://sysadmin:mypassword@172.31.96.1:5432/db_dev'

But that IP address changes on every reboot, so that is not convenient at all.
It looks like networking has changed quite a bit between WSL and WSL2, but I cannot find an acceptable solution to this I would say rather basic issue.

There are no problems with my Postgres config, as I can connect using the ip address.

Comment: just to be clear, I have already tried workaround to forward a port, like: socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:5432,reuseaddr,fork TCP:$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | tail -n1 | cut -d " " -f 2):5432 But I am looking for a more permanent solution, where I don't have to run a command everytime I restart the wsl2 environment

Comment: I ended up creating a task in VSCODE to execute the command above, still hope that Microsoft will provide a simple way to connec to the host from WSL2 (like in WSL1)